# Google's Dart "tracker" sample application doesn't work under Dart Editor environment

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

There is a very nice task tracker Dart demo application at the following URL.

https://www.dartlang.org/samples/tracker/

When I download the source code and run it in the Dart editor with Dartium, the app works, but the layout of the controls is completely wrong. It looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should just make your browser windows less wide to get the same layout as shown in your above link.

Comment: This. Here is what the sample looks like when opened in its own tab instead of a frame: https://www.dartlang.org/samples/tracker/example/index.html